# How to reload a module that was loaded by another module?

Tags: python

I have an intermediate module that serves as an `export_file`, however, at development time, I couldn't figure out how to reload everything that the `export_file` has imported.

`main_module.py`

```
def func1(): print("func1")
# def func2(): print("func2)  # to be uncommented later for testing if reload worked.
```

`export_file.py`

```
from main_module import *  # for sake of simplicity.
```

Finally, `main_file.py`

```
from export_file import as exp  # for simplicity
```

Now, if `func2` is uncommented, how can I feel the impact on `main_file.py`?
I tried reload, `importlib`, `runpy` modules, run them everywhere, added a special function inside `export_file` for this purpose, but I couldn't get it to work, neither for love nor for money.

EDIT:

[exact sequence of commands ran in `main_file` interactive console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgpkG.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Could you explain what you mean by "reload everything"?  Why would you need to load them a second time?

Comment: Hi Danie, so its because I'm at development stage and in the middle of so much work that I can't bother to restart the console but I still want to feel some change made somewhere else on the fly. (I'm guessing that this is why `reload` module was invented). By reload everthing I' basically want to see that there is now something called `func2` defined in main file.

Comment: Is this in an interactive console?

Comment: Yes. `PyCharm Console`.

Comment: What happened when you ran `importlib.reload`?  That's what I use.

Comment: So, the changes in `main_module` were not reflected. I even tried running it in the intermediate module (but inside a function) then call the function from `main_file` to no avail.

Comment: Would you mind editing your post and showing the exact sequence of commands, including `importlib.reload`, you entered?  That way, we can hopefully find out what happened.

Comment: Added. For your attention.

Comment: Instead of linking to your core, please edit your post and type it out.